# Windows update 2919355 causes our SQL based app perf to drop to 1/6 of previous perf

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a VB6 app calling out to a local **SQL2008R2** instance.

We have had complaints about it's performance dropping considerably.

After a lot of experimental research, we have determined at least 1 cause of this speed decrease.

Whilst running on a base Windows 8.1 the system is relatively fine.

A given benchmark takes **approx 0.8 seconds**.

Then install Microsoft's KB2919355 and the same operation **takes 5.0 seconds**.

**Thats a 6X drop in performance.**

Uninstall this same update and the performance returns to previous levels.

My usual google fu has not managed to find anything specific on this topic. this may be because of all the media surrounding the launch of this particular update.

I'm led to believe that this update is mandatory if you're to install windows 8.1 Update 1.

we have some other machines displaying this behaviour but without the ability to remove this update

**Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? 
Does anyone know of a way to solve this perf issue other than to remove the offending update?**

FYI we also have this effect on a number of Windows 7 machines. We are currently chasing down the offending update on this stack.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355 the only included update that mentions sql is  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2920006. You might look and see if it has anything to do with your issue.